# How can i fix maven "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-3

When i run `mvn -v`,i got following error:

> mvn -v 
>
> 错误: 加载主类 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher 时出现 LinkageError
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void java.util.zip.Inflater.initIDs()'

My .zsh env setup is:

> export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home 
> export CLASS_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib 
> export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/install/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin

I tried download the new version && install again, but still not working,please help.

Comment: which directory do you run `mvn -v`

Comment: install_dir/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin, but i think directory is not important after cmd `source .zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

Is your Maven version downloaded correctly? The `binary zip archive` version needs to be downloaded.

Then you need to configure environment variables, like this:

export M2_HOME=`your maven root path`

export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin

Maven Download Link: https://ftp.wayne.edu/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip

Comment: It does't work even if I download & extract & cd & run cmd `./mvn -v`

Comment: It works when I run cmd like this `sudo mvn -v`. btw, my macos is upgraded to `big sur` a week ago.

Comment: @markwave Did you ever figure this out?